# The close (x) icon on the dialog window in Flutter is not responsive to touch

Tags: flutter

The code I have modified so far is as follows. I used the Positioned widget in the Stack widget to render the close icon on the screen. However, when this dialog window pops up, the close icon doesn't work at all. It doesn't seem like a difficult problem, but no matter how much I try to fix it, it doesn't work. Can someone please help me?

```
void signInDialog(BuildContext context, {required ValueChanged onValue}) {
  showGeneralDialog(
    context: context,
    barrierLabel: "Barrier",
    barrierDismissible: true,
    barrierColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
    transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) {
      return Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 620,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(24, 36, 24, 36),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.95),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                offset: const Offset(0, 30),
                blurRadius: 60,
              ),
              const BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.black45,
                offset: Offset(0, 30),
                blurRadius: 60,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          child: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            body: Stack(
              clipBehavior: Clip.none,
              children: [
                SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      const Text(
                        "Sign In",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 34,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
                        child: Text(
                          "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SignInForm(),
                      const Row(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: Divider(),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                            child: Text(
                              "OR",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black26,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Expanded(child: Divider()),
                        ],
                      ),
                      const Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 24),
                        child: Text(
                          "Sign up with Email, Apple or Google",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [
                          IconButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              signUpDialog(context, onValue: (value) {
                             
                              });
                            },
                            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                            icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                              "assets/icons/email_box.svg",
                              height: 64,
                              width: 64,
                            ),
                          ),
                          IconButton(
                            onPressed: () {},
                            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                            icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                              "assets/icons/apple_box.svg",
                              height: 64,
                              width: 64,
                            ),
                          ),
                          IconButton(
                            onPressed: () {},
                            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                            icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                              "assets/icons/google_box.svg",
                              height: 64,
                              width: 64,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),

                Positioned(
                  top: 0,
                  right: 0,
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                      child: const Icon(
                        Icons.close,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
    transitionBuilder: (_, anim, __, child) {
      Tween<Offset> tween;
      tween = Tween(begin: const Offset(0, -1), end: Offset.zero);

      return SlideTransition(
        position: tween.animate(
          CurvedAnimation(parent: anim, curve: Curves.easeInOut),
        ),
        child: child,
      );
    },
  ).then(onValue);
}
```

1. I tried printing a log using the print function in the onTap of the Positioned widget, but the log doesn't show up in the console at all. In other words, it seems like the close icon itself is not being touched.
2. I tried using the Align widget instead of the Positioned widget, but the close icon still can't be touched.

Answer (score 1):

you should use TextButton which gives a touchy impression better than GestureDetector. you can modify above code as below:

```
    TextButton(

          onPressed: () { 
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: const Icon(
              Icons.close,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

the complete code will be:

```
 void signInDialog(BuildContext context, {required ValueChanged onValue}) {
showGeneralDialog(
  context: context,
  barrierLabel: "Barrier",
  barrierDismissible: true,
  barrierColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
  transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
  pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        height: 620,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(24, 36, 24, 36),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.95),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
              offset: const Offset(0, 30),
              blurRadius: 60,
            ),
            const BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black45,
              offset: Offset(0, 30),
              blurRadius: 60,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          body: Stack(
            clipBehavior: Clip.none,
            children: [
              SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    const Text(
                      "Sign In",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 34,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
                      child: Text(
                        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SignInForm(),
                    const Row(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: Divider(),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                          child: Text(
                            "OR",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black26,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(child: Divider()),
                      ],
                    ),
                    const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 24),
                      child: Text(
                        "Sign up with Email, Apple or Google",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: [
                        IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            signUpDialog(context, onValue: (value) {

                            });
                          },
                          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                          icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                            "assets/icons/email_box.svg",
                            height: 64,
                            width: 64,
                          ),
                        ),
                        IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                          icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                            "assets/icons/apple_box.svg",
                            height: 64,
                            width: 64,
                          ),
                        ),
                        IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                          icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                            "assets/icons/google_box.svg",
                            height: 64,
                            width: 64,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),

              Positioned(
                top: 0,
                right: 0,
                child:  TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    child: const Icon(
                      Icons.close,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
  transitionBuilder: (_, anim, __, child) {
    Tween<Offset> tween;
    tween = Tween(begin: const Offset(0, -1), end: Offset.zero);

    return SlideTransition(
      position: tween.animate(
        CurvedAnimation(parent: anim, curve: Curves.easeInOut),
      ),
      child: child,
    );
  },
).then(onValue);
```

}